# How to Import a Project on ESP-IDF using VS Code

Tags: vscode-extensions, esp32, esp-idf

I have a project I have written, I was already able to compile at work. Now I am trying to compile the same project on my personal comoputer. It gives me a lot of include path errors. I know I have to change some things in the CMake file however I dont know what to change exactly. I have had problems importing projects from Git as well.

The Question is: How can I import and compile an existing ESP IDF project on VS Code?